# How to compare dates in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I have two dates: how do I compare which one is greater date in Objective-C?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS: Compare two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112075/ios-compare-two-dates)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From NSDate class reference:

> **NSDate -compare:** Returns an NSComparisonResult
>   value that indicates the temporal
>   ordering of the receiver and another
>   given date.
>
> - (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSDate *)anotherDate
>
> Parameters anotherDate The date with
>   which to compare the receiver.
>
> This value must not be nil. If the
>   value is nil, the behavior is
>   undefined and may change in future
>   versions of Mac OS X.
>
> Return Value If:
>
> The receiver and anotherDate are
>   exactly equal to each other,
>   NSOrderedSame
>
> The receiver is later in time than
>   anotherDate, NSOrderedDescending
>
> The receiver is earlier in time than
>   anotherDate, NSOrderedAscending.
>
> Discussion This method detects
>   sub-second differences between dates.
>   If you want to compare dates with a
>   less fine granularity, use
>   timeIntervalSinceDate: to compare the
>   two dates.

Comment: You'll need to use NSDateFormat to convert your strings to dates.

Comment: There's also -[NSDate earlierDate:] and -[NSDate laterDate:], which are more appropriate if what you really care about is finding the latest of two dates.