# NSDate comparison in custom format Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

I want compare two dates. I am getting device date in yyyy-dd-mm format and getting mm-dd-yyyy from webservices. I want to change device date format and get that changed date in `NSDate` object. Here is my code:

```
 NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];     
 NSLog(@"today : %@", today);
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM dd yy"];
 NSString *tString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
 NSLog(@"tString : %@",tString);
 NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:tString];
 NSLog(@"date : %@",date);
```

Comment: what this [dateFormatter set] does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying date coming from webservice is in mm-dd-yyyy format..Then convert it into NSDate like this

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy"];
NSDate *convertedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:yourDateStringFromWeb];
```

You have device date already with you..Now you can compare two NSDate objects in many ways..See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994855/comparing-dates-in-iphone-programming) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693316/how-to-compare-dates-in-iphone-sdk)..

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: I tried above one. But when I convert that into NSdata object and again print on console, the format changed from MM-dd-yyyy

Comment: Output is: today : 2011-05-23 12:38:49 +0000

Comment: iSwap, the main thing is you can compare between two NSDate object, you dont have to make them strings..

Comment: " I want to change device date format and get that changed date in NSDate object" , NSDate doesnt have any format. Format is only when you convert it to string to display..

Comment: @iSwap, confirm this, You are getting a date from webservice (like 5-27-2011) in strings, you want to convert it to NSDate object. Then compare it with a date which you already have in device (which is a string in format yyyy-dd-mm like 2011-27-5). Is this your requirement?