# How do I determine whether an NSDate (including time) has passed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate

How do I determine whether an NSDate (including time) has passed?  I need to basically compare today's date to a date in the db but am stumped.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ([someDate timeIntervalSinceNow] < 0.0) {
    // Date has passed
}
```

Comment: I put that into a category method so you can use `someDate.isInPast`.

Comment: your code is comparing only date not the time. Like i am comparing same day but different time like this: 1/1/2015 5:00:00 and 1/1/2015 7:00:00 with this date it's showing me the Date has passed.

Comment: +Daddy, not sure what you mean. According to the documentation this method should be perfect: "The time interval between the date object and the current date and time. (read-only) If the date object is earlier than the current date and time, this property’s value is negative."

Comment: For use in Date Extension: `func isPast() -> Bool {
        if (self.timeIntervalSinceNow < 0.0) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }`

Answer (score 6):

you need to use an NSDate comparison, many answers on here will assist you.

[iOS: Compare two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112075/ios-compare-two-dates)

logic will need tweaking, but this should set you in the right direction:

```
- (BOOL)date:(NSDate*)date isBefore:(BOOL)before otherDate:(NSDate*)otherDate ;
{
    if(before && ([date compare:otherDate] == NSOrderedAscending))
        return YES;
    if (!before && ([date compare:otherDate] == NSOrderedDescending))
        return YES;  
}
```

usage:

```
if([self date:yourDate isBefore:YES otherDate:[NSDate date]])
```

Comment: On a coding-style note: your second parameter should really be named something like `isBefore:`. Reading out loud "date:X isBefore:YES/NO otherDate:Y" sounds a lot better IMO than "date:X is:YES/NO otherDate:Y".

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
[NSDate date];
```

to get an NSDate object representing the current time and date.

Then compare that to the date you are analysing, for example:

```
if ([currentDate timeIntervalSince1970] > [yourDate timeIntervalSince1970]) {
// yourDate is in the past
}
```

you can use this to compare any two dates. Hope this helps.

Comment: or do it inline: ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] > [yourDate timeIntervalSince1970])

Comment: I was just providing a more general solution for comparing dates - comparing a date to now is rather a niche case. In practice though, you probably would just use timeIntervalSinceNow in this particular scenario.