# Check if today's date falls in between start date and end date

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Current date** should not go before **start date** and after **end date** but it can be equal to **start date** or **end date**.

How should i modify the code?

```
for(AllBookings *book in bookarray)
{

    NSString *startdte = book.StartDate; //taking start date from array
    NSString *enddte = book.EndDate;
    NSDate *start = [self getDateFromJSON:startdte];
    NSDate *end = [self getDateFromJSON:enddte];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

    NSTimeInterval fromTime = [start timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    NSTimeInterval toTime = [end timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    NSTimeInterval currTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

    if((fromTime<currTime) && (toTime>=currTime))//checking if currnt is in btw strt n end
    {
        success = TRUE;
        break;

    }
    else {
        success = FALSE;
    }

}
```

Comment: Check here you find many EXACTLY same question.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112075/ios-compare-two-dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the working code which i am using in my application, i have made changes according to your requirement:

```
 -(void)isSuitableTime{
  NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [df setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

   NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
   NSString *currentTimeString = [df stringFromDate: currentTime];

   NSDate *gpsTimeCurrent= [df dateFromString:currentTimeString];
   NSDate *gpsTimeFrom = [df dateFromString:@"09:00" ];
   NSDate *gpsTimeTo = [df dateFromString:@"17:00"];

   NSTimeInterval intervalFromTimeToCurrent = 
             [gpsTimeCurrent timeIntervalSinceDate:gpsTimeFrom];

   NSTimeInterval intervalCurrentToTimeTo = 
                 [gpsTimeTo timeIntervalSinceDate:gpsTimeCurrent];

   NSLog(@"intervalToTimeToCurrent is %f",intervalCurrentToTimeTo);

   if ((intervalFromTimeToCurrent>0) && (intervalCurrentToTimeTo >0)) {
                NSLog(@"In my time range");
    } 
    else {
    NSLog(@"Out of my time range");
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method mate

```
- (BOOL)isDate:(NSDate *)date inRangeFirstDate:(NSDate *)firstDate lastDate:(NSDate *)lastDate {
       return [date compare:firstDate] == NSOrderedDescending && [date compare:lastDate]  == NSOrderedAscending;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the NSDate's `compare:` method instead of `if (current > fromTime)`

```
From the class reference:

If:
The receiver and anotherDate are exactly equal to each other, NSOrderedSame.
The receiver is later in time than anotherDate, NSOrderedDescending.
The receiver is earlier in time than anotherDate, NSOrderedAscending.


you can use

if([current compare: From] == NSOrderedDescending||NSOrderedSame
   && [current compare: Totime]== NSOrderedAescending||NSOrderedSame)
{
  // Current is between to and From 
}
```