# Find difference between two dates is exactly 1 year

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

This is my code and it perfectly returns number of days and months between two dates. i want to validate this like the difference between two dates should be exactly one year.like if u select july 29 2013 as start date and july 30 2014 as end date it should not be allowed to execute more.please help thanks in advance.

```
    NSString *sta = txtStartdate.text; // This is the start date

    NSString *en =   txtEnddate.text;   //this is end date

    NSDateFormatter *f = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [f setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    NSDate *startDat = [f dateFromString:sta];

    NSDate *endDat = [f dateFromString:en];

    [f release];

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit ;

    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags
                                                fromDate:startDat
                                                  toDate:endDat options:0];
    NSInteger months = [components month];
    NSInteger days = [components day];
    NSInteger years = [components year];

    NSLog(@"Number of months %d",months);

    NSLog(@"Number of days %d",days);

    NSLog(@"Number of years %d",years);

    [gregorian release];

    if(years < 1 )// This code works fine...i've edited it.. @wain helped
    {
        //
```

}

Comment: You can compare two NSDate like explained in the post :

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6112171/1343969

Comment: Why aren't you using the year date component?

Comment: @Wain how can i modify the code with year date component.sorry i am new to the iphone

Comment: NSInteger yer=[components year];

Comment: possible duplicate of [IOS: compare two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112075/ios-compare-two-dates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `NSYearCalendarUnit` to `unitFlags`, then when you have obtained the `components` you can request the `year`. This will deal with leap years better than you trying to count months and days or calculate the end date (unless you use the components to add a single year to the date to get the end date).

Comment: yeah..it worked..i've added NSYearCalendarUnit to unitFlags and reqstd year on compnents..i've updated the code above..thanks alot..@wain