# Is there any particular format for compare two dates in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate

I compare two dates with compare method .When I'm using date formatter as sedate style it return right answer.If I'm set the date formatter in custom way ;the answer was wrong.Isn't possible to compare two dates with custom formatter in iOS?

Comment: Formatting dates (i.e. `NSString` <=> `NSDate`) and comparing dates are two entirely different things.

Comment: Why don't you compare dates without formatter?

Comment: you can follow this [link][1]. This types of questions are already asked.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112075/ios-compare-two-dates

Answer (score 2):

```
if ([date1 isEqualToDate:date2]) {

}
```

This is the simple way to Compare two dates...

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try this    

 if ([date1 compare:date2]==NSOrderedSame)
{
}
```