# Core Data Error - NSDate localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare: unrecognised selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, avfoundation, unrecognized-selector

I have searched for the last several hours but have yet to find an answer. I implemented an AVFoundation camera, Im saving the image data to disk and storing only the path in core data. Everything works fine but after a random number of taken photos I get this error:

CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSDate localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

This is my fetch request code:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Photo"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"notebook = %@", notebookItem];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateTaken"
                                                              ascending:NO
                                                               selector:@selector(compare:)]];
```

And here is how I save the data in a separate class:

```
//I create a photo Object to save to core data and set properties like dateTaken and tittle

//Here is where I create the path name
NSDate *dateString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
NSString *path = [formatter stringFromDate:dateString];

//Now I save to disk
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
// the path to write file
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];
NSLog(@"path: %@", path);
[[[self captureManager] ImageDataObject] writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

photo.imagePath = filePath;

[notebookItem addPhotosObject:photo];
[self.SharedDocumentHandlerInstance saveDocument];
```

I tracked down the point of crash and it occurs in the line of code where I save the document (the last one above) but maybe the fetch request is the one that causes it. I also set self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil in my table. And again, this error occurs after a random number of photos is taken. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Best guess is that you're violating the multi-threading restrictions of CoreData and trying to modify CoreData from a background thread.

Comment: I thought that too, might setting atomically:YES be it (Im not using any threads).

Comment: You're using AVFoundation, so you're using threads.  AVFoundation callbacks are made on background threads.  atomically:YES isn't the problem, that just changes how the file is written out (it  writes temp, then moves temp to name)

Comment: How can I make the save happen in in the main thread then. And thanks for the help!

Comment: Many different approaches, best bet is probably to search SO for CoreData background and/or dig out the Apple CoreData concurrency documentation which gives a good review of all the approaches.  For your case, probably the simplest is going to be `-[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:]`

Comment: Tried it and the error persists. This is whats really bugging me: [__NSDate localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: @David, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that you cannot call `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` on an NSDate. You need to change that to `compare:`. Check through the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on `NSDate`.

The method `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` requires an `NSString` ([Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)).

This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112075/ios-compare-two-dates) may also be helpful.

Also Table 1 in this web page [Creating and Using Sort Descriptors](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Articles/Creating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001845-BAJEAIEE)

Comment: If you notice, it is set to compare. However you're right in a way, In a view controller in which I do a search based on date, it was set to localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare and this was causing the crash.

Comment: I did notice. In my answer I didn't mention your code. I made it clear that you cannot call `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare` on an `NSDate`, in direct response to your error written into your question. So in fact I am correct. Happy to have helped!!!